# psycopgn2 não é reconhecido pela virtual env no django

Tags: python, postgresql, django

minha configuração do banco no django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'teste1',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432'
    }
}
```

error encontrado:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module")
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
asgiref         3.7.2
Django          4.2.6
pip             23.3
psycopg2        2.9.9
psycopg2-binary 2.9.9
sqlparse        0.4.4
```

mesmo com o psycopgn instalado dentro da virtual env ainda apresenta o error, já instalei e reinstalei o django, psycopg2 2.9.9 e psycopg2-binary 2.9.9 e sem exito alguem sabe o que pode ser???

Comment: você já fez essa pergunta antes, podemos ver o erro, mas não está sendo possível entender como reproduzir o problema para tentar uma solução. Recomendo revisar a documentação do site, e como criar um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Queira [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/587917/70) melhorando-a, que automaticamente ela é destacada para que a comunidade revise para ver se [atende à finalidade do site](/help). Note que se for um problema de mera instalação e infraestrutura, este não é o site correto, talvez possa ser reformulada no [sf] ou no [dba.se], mas é importante ler as regras de cada comunidade antes para se certificar. O campo de comentários está desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado naquela postagem.